# What is the root Exception in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the root Exception in Hibernate.
I need handling all exceptions in my methods. 
DataAccessException, HibernateException, PersistenceException or HibernateException?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are the hibernate exception hierarchy.

```
java.lang.Object
  extended by java.lang.Throwable
      extended by java.lang.Exception
          extended by java.lang.RuntimeException
              extended by org.hibernate.HibernateException
```

Below are the Direct Known Subclasses of HibernateException :

> AuditException, BatchFailedException, CacheException,
>   CallbackException, IdentifierGenerationException,
>   InstantiationException, JDBCException, LazyInitializationException,
>   MappingException, MultipleBagFetchException, NonUniqueObjectException,
>   NonUniqueResultException, OptimisticLockException,
>   PersistentObjectException, PropertyAccessException,
>   PropertyValueException, QueryException, SerializationException,
>   SessionException, StaleStateException, TooManyRowsAffectedException,
>   TransactionException, TransientObjectException, TypeMismatchException,
>   UnknownProfileException, UnresolvableObjectException,
>   ValidationFailure, WrongClassException

You can use super parent say

> Exception

to handle your exception for general case, for specific to hibernate you can go with

> HibernateException

For more detail for same you can refer - [HibernateException hierarchy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html)